# Using the flush left align environment flalign

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align

When using the `flalign`, I either get LHS and the `=` on te far left and the RHS on the far right.

[image]

```
\begin{flalign}
x & = & 1
\end{flalign}
```

Or I the equation centers itself when I try

[image]

```
\begin{flalign}
x & = 1
\end{flalign}
```

How can I get everything on the LHS?

Comment: Do you want all your equations to be flushed left?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina yes for this set but not everyone in the doc.

Comment: `flalign` means *“full length align”*, not “flush left”

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add an alignment character at the end:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c
\end{flalign}
\begin{flalign}
f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c &
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

Note that in a regular `align`ment, you only use a single `&` around the relation you wish to align with.

To have *all* equations flush left, add the `fleqn` option to your document class (or the packages that use it, like [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)):

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
```

Comment: One thing I noticed that I don't like about it compared with `tabbing` is the right alignment of the expression on the LHS of th `=`.  Can this be aligned in the same manner as `tabbing` with a left justification?

Comment: @dustin: See the update in [Labeling equations or the use of subequations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119086/5764) on how to obtain your `tabbing`-like alignment.